# Graph to show which database I'm using

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm currently thinking off a way to show which database is the graph showing when I get the information.Currently my dash graph looks like this and I would like that it shows which databse the graph currently used to get the info, I have two databases in the application.Should I make a new  layout = go.Layout fuction in the def graph or elsewhere?Do you guys have any suggestions?

[this is where I would like to show the name of the database I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyZVk.jpg)

I have this in my html layout at the moment.On the left side you can see my databases that are shown in the html,but I need to show the db in the graph output.

```
controls = dbc.FormGroup(
    [
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(
            html.Div(["Start Time: ", constants.start_date_picker],
                    ),
                ),
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div([ constants.start_time_picker ])
            )
        ],style={"marginBottom":"0.5em"}),
                dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(
            html.Div(["End Time: ", constants.end_date_picker]),
                ),
            dbc.Col(constants.end_time_picker 
                ),
        ]),
     html.Hr(),
    dbc.Row([
         dbc.Col([
                     html.Div(["Database"])
             ]),
         dbc.Col([
                     constants.database
             ])
     ],style={"marginBottom":"1em"}),          
    dbc.Row([
    ],style={"marginBottom":"1em"}),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
                    html.Div(["Language"])
            ]),
        dbc.Col([
                    constants.language
            ])
    ],style={"marginBottom":"0.5em"}),
    html.Hr(),
    dbc.Button(
        id='submit_button',
        n_clicks=0,
        children='Submit',
        color='primary',
        block=True
        ),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id="alert7"),#appcallback output 3
    html.Div(id="link7"),#appcallback  download sheet output
    # html.Div(id="alert8")#appcallback excel
    #html.Div(id="barchart7"),#appcallback pie output 2
    # html.Div(id="pie7")
    ]
)

sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2('Input', style=constants.TEXT_STYLE),
        # html.H3('Parameters', style=constants.TEXT_STYLE),
        html.Hr(),
        controls
    ],
    style=constants.SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)

layout = html.Div([sidebar, content])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add a new title and used my paramter database and it works fine

```
fig = px.bar(dataframe, x=dataframe['Timestamp'], y=dataframe['Duration'], title=("The database is") + ' ' + (database))
```